# Rails test database getting wrong column type on geographic columns

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-3.2, postgis

We have a rails app that uses postgis and activerecord-postgis-adapter for geographic information search.  However, it doesn't work right in the test database.  In development and production database, geographic columns get the type "geography(Point, 4236)".  In test, those same columns have the type "geometry".  This means that geographic searches don't do spherical geographic distance ... they just do plain cartesian geometry, which means the numbers are typically off by about 100,000.  Boo.

Here's what it looks like in **schema.rb:**

```
create_table "buyers", :force => true do |t|
  # snip 
  t.spatial  "geocoded_coordinates",    :limit => {:srid=>4326, :type=>"point", :geographic=>true}
end
```

**And in database.yml:**

```
development: &development
  adapter: postgis
  database: lvs_dev
  username: postgres
  host:     "lrd-db"
  template: template_postgis

test:
  <<: *development
  database: lvs_test
```

The resulting columns in the database (via psql):

**lvs_dev:**

```
lvs_dev=# \d+ buyers
Table "public.buyers"
# snip
geocoded_coordinates    | geography(Point,4326)       |                                                      | main     |
```

**lvs_test:**

```
lvs_dev=# \d+ buyers
Table "public.buyers"
# snip
geocoded_coordinates    | geometry                    |                                                      | main     |
```

So ... what gives here?  Any ideas why rails / rake is creating a different DB schema in development and test?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try dropping and recreating the test DB, then running the migrations again?  Also, check to see if it's reloading the test DB from the schema somewhere instead of running the migrations.

Comment: I looked into it more and it is set up to load the DB from the schema, so you want to make sure that the special commands are in the schema and getting loaded correctly.  There is a way to have it load from a file w/ custom commands if the schema isn't working for you: "config.active_record.schema_format = :sql" more details here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1560150/what-is-db-development-structure-sql-in-a-rails-project