# What is the structure.sql used for?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I'm curious what the point of the `structure.sql` file is. It seems to be updated and created every time rails migrations are run. So it seems to be a visual representation of our database. What else can it be used for?

When one runs `structure:load`, what does it do? What does it mean to load a structure file into a database? Why would you need to do that?

Should one be committing the `structure.sql` file?

Comment: This question seems to have some information for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1560150/what-is-db-development-structure-sql-in-a-rails-project

Answer (score 1):

Seems like your rails app is configured to use the sql schema format

```
#/config/application.rb
...
 config.active_record.schema_format = :sql
...
```

the structure.sql is in place of a schema.db.

Running `db:structure:load` ( or `db:schema:load`) will load your entire database.  You only need to do this when bringing on a new app instance from scratch.  After awhile, your migration files will become quite lengthy and it will be better to do a load first, then a migration when bringing up a new app instance